# Sonar runner execution Failure

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I'm running SonarQube analysis in preview mode, and i get the error below. However, when I run the full analysis it is  successfully completed. Anyone know how to fix this?

SonarQube: 4.5.6

Sonar Runner: 2.4

> ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
>   org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar    at
>   org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
>     at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
>     at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
>     at
>   org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
>     at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)     at
>   org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)   at
>   org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)   at
>   org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53) Caused by:
>   org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Fail to decorate

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to this. Even though you are running preview analysis which doesn't store results to sonar DB but Jenkins need to access Sonar. In this scenario you need to add sonar credentials to Jenkins inorder to access sonar.